# Use the derived class value from the base class

Tags: c++, qt

Trying to create a widget in the baseclass and the only thing that will change in the widget depending on what derived class we call is the title.

```
class BaseView : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit BaseView(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
     QString title; 
     virtual QString getTitle() const {
         return title;
     }
```

BaseView.cpp :

```
BaseView::BaseView(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {

     title = "test"
}

void BaseView::createTopWidget() {
    QGroupBox *topWidget = new QGroupBox(getTitle());
    ....
}
```

The in the derived class header:

```
class DerivedView : public BaseView {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit DerivedView(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
     QString getTitle() const {
         return title;
     }
```

And in the derived constructor I set title to "correct".

When I run the program by creating a DerivedView, the title is still "test". How can I do this so I will call and get at derived class value from the base class?

Comment: What is the relationship between `getTitle` and `getTopWidgetMessage`? I.e., you define `getTitle` as virtual but never call it anywhere -- what's the point?

Comment: oh, they are suppose to be the same. renamed them for this example but forgot to rename them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very firm grasp on C++, **you must not call virtual functions in a constructor**. The problem is that during subobject creation, the type of the object is the base subobject, not the derived object, so the virtual function call is dispatched to the "wrong" function.

Baby example:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual int foo() { return 8; }

    Base() { set_something(foo()); }  // who're you gonna call?
};
struct Derived
{
    virtual int foo() { return -12; }
};

Derived d;
```

Now in the base constructor for `d.Base()`, the function that gets called is `d.Base::foo()`, not `d.Derived::foo()`.

Moreover, by the time the base class constructor runs, the member variable `title` has only been set to `"test"`, and it has not yet been overwritten by the assignment in the derived constructor, which runs only *after* the base constructor completes.

You can solve your problem by passing the title in the constructor explicitly:

```
class BaseView : public QWidget
{
public:
    BaseView(QWidget * parent = 0, QString const & t = "test")
    : QWidget(parent), title(t)
    {
        something.set_title(title);
    }

    // ...
};

class DerivedView
{
public:
    DerivedView(QWidget * parent = 0)
    : BaseView(parent, "correct")
    { }
};
```

Comment: Oh okay. Yeah i figured that the baseclass would not be able to get stuff from its derived class very easily. However, is there any other ways of doing this? The title string will be quite long and I will be doing the same thing on other objects. I guess i might have to drop the idea of a baseclass that creates everything..

Comment: @chikuba: see my update; I'd pass all the requisite information in a constructor and just call the desired initializer in the derived constructor.

Comment: Also, i noticed that you canged the constructor of the derived view. If the derived view has a parent (another widget), woudlnt that parent be sent to the baseview aswell? I see no reason why the dervied widget would be the parent of the baseview.

Comment: is this a common way of doing things or should i come up with another solution? perheps init the groupbox in the derived class

Comment: Also, you said that I never should call the viritual function in the constructor, which i dont do. So why do I still have issues? Is it cus I run the function that uses the variable from the constructor, and the derived constructor wont be called until that is done?

Comment: @chikuba: The details may vary, and I'm not too familiar with how you have to chain the parent pointers, so feel free to adapt that to whatever you actually need. Who is actually setting the title text? Who is calling `createTopWidget()`? Are you sure that isn't happening in the base constructor?

Comment: read this example (further down when he talks about dogs): http://www.gidforums.com/t-24611.html If I called that print function from the base constructor, it would grab the value 0 ?